# Adding row values to a group by result

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

I have a dataframe that looks something like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([1,'A','X','1/2/22 12:00:00AM','1/1/22 12:00:00 AM'],
[1,'A','X','1/1/22 1:00:00AM','1/1/22 12:00:00 AM'],
[1,'A','Y','1/3/22 12:00:00AM','1/2/22 12:00:00 AM'],
[1,'B','X','1/1/22 1:00:00AM','1/1/22 12:00:00 AM'],
[2,'A','X','1/2/22 12:00:00AM','1/1/22 12:00:00 AM'],
[2,'A','X','1/1/22 1:00:00AM','1/1/22 12:00:00 AM'],
columns = ['ID','Category','Site','Task Completed','Access Completed'])
```

| ID | Category | Site | Task Completed | Access Completed |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | X | 1/2/22 12:00:00AM | 1/1/22 12:00:00 AM |
| 1 | A | Y | 1/3/22 12:00:00AM | 1/2/22 12:00:00 AM |
| 1 | A | X | 1/1/22 1:00:00AM | 1/1/22 12:00:00 AM |
| 1 | B | X | 1/1/22 1:00:00AM | 1/1/22 12:00:00 AM |
| 2 | A | X | 1/2/22 12:00:00AM | 1/1/22 12:00:00 AM |
| 2 | A | X | 1/1/22 1:00:00AM | 1/1/22 12:00:00 AM |

Quick note - the **access completed date** is the same for every ID/Site/Category pair no matter how many instances there are of them.

What I want to find is the time difference (in hours) between Access Completed and the ***first*** Task Completed for every ID/Category/Site combination within the dataset. I also want to include that first task completed date and the Access completed date along side the result.

I am able to get the time difference calculation but I'm not sure how to tie in the first task completed date and the Access completed date for each of the ID/Category/Site combos. Here's what I have so far:

```
df[['Task Completed','Access Completed']] = \
    df[['Task Completed','Access Completed']].apply(lambda x: pd.to_datetime(x))

res = df.sort_values('Task Completed').groupby(['ID','Category','Site']).first()
res = res['Task Completed'].sub(res['Access Completed'])\
    .dt.total_seconds().div(3600).reset_index(drop=False).rename(
        columns={0:'Time Difference'})
```

This has an output of:

```
   ID Category Site  Time Difference
0   1        A    X              1.0
1   1        A    Y             24.0
2   1        B    X              1.0
3   2        A    X              1.0
```

This is my intended result:

| ID | Category | Site | Time Difference | First Task Completed | Access Completed |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | X | 1 | 1/1/22 1:00:00AM | 1/1/22 12:00:00 AM |
| 1 | A | Y | 24 | 1/3/22 12:00:00AM | 1/2/22 12:00:00 AM |
| 1 | B | X | 1 | 1/1/22 1:00:00AM | 1/1/22 12:00:00 AM |
| 2 | A | X | 1 | 1/1/22 1:00:00AM | 1/1/22 12:00:00 AM |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Process used:

- First convert the dates into appropriate format to allow subtraction
- Remove the duplicates, and keep only the first date.
- With duplicates removed, now calculate the differences
- Needed to re-order, rename and format the columns to match the expected output

```py
import pandas as pd

cols = ['ID','Category','Site','Task Completed','Access Completed']

df = pd.DataFrame([[1,'A','X','1/2/22 12:00:00AM','1/1/22 12:00:00 AM'],
[1,'A','X','1/1/22 1:00:00AM','1/1/22 12:00:00 AM'],
[1,'A','Y','1/3/22 12:00:00AM','1/2/22 12:00:00 AM'],
[1,'B','X','1/1/22 1:00:00AM','1/1/22 12:00:00 AM'],
[2,'A','X','1/2/22 12:00:00AM','1/1/22 12:00:00 AM'],
[2,'A','X','1/1/22 1:00:00AM','1/1/22 12:00:00 AM']],
columns = cols)

#Convert to datetime
df[['Task Completed','Access Completed']] = df[['Task Completed','Access Completed']].apply(lambda x: pd.to_datetime(x))

# Remove duplicate columns - only keep the first task completed.
res = df.sort_values('Task Completed')\
    .drop_duplicates(subset=["ID", "Category", 'Site'], keep='first')\
    .sort_index()

# Calculate time difference
res['Time Difference'] = res['Task Completed'].sub(res['Access Completed']).dt.total_seconds().div(3600)

#Re-order and re-name columns
cols.insert(3,'Time Difference')
res = res[cols].rename(columns={"Task Completed": "First Task Completed"})

# Convert the dates back to desired format
res["First Task Completed"] = res["First Task Completed"].dt.strftime('%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S %p')
res["Access Completed"] = res["Access Completed"].dt.strftime('%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S %p')

print(res)
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
   ID Category Site  Time Difference    First Task Completed   Access Completed  
1   1        A    X              1.0  01/01/2022 01:00:00 AM   01/01/2022 00:00:00 AM  
2   1        A    Y             24.0  01/03/2022 00:00:00 AM   01/02/2022 00:00:00 AM  
3   1        B    X              1.0  01/01/2022 01:00:00 AM   01/01/2022 00:00:00 AM  
5   2        A    X              1.0  01/01/2022 01:00:00 AM   01/01/2022 00:00:00 AM
```

Comment: This was the right course of action, thank you.